# ec2 instance cant mount glusterfs server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, glusterfs, fstab

My EC2 instance tries to mount glusterfs volume whic located on another EC2 instance .

client instance's /etc/fstab file contains:

```
glusterserver1:/export/brick1 /mnt/glusterfs glusterfs defaults 0 0
```

when I try to mount it

```
mnt -a
```

But it gives error. The glusterfs log for my client like below:

```
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.757834] I [glusterfsd.c:1666:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.3.1
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.777490] E [socket.c:1715:socket_connect_finish] 0-glusterfs: connection to  failed (Connection refused)
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.777581] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1787:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: failed to connect with remote-host: Transport endpoint is not connected
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.777608] I [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1790:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: -1 connect attempts left
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.777847] W [glusterfsd.c:831:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_transport_notify+0x28) [0x7f604baf7018] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0xc0) [0x7f604bafb850] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs() [0x40c066]))) 0-: received signum (1), shutting down
[2013-02-19 17:49:46.777894] I [fuse-bridge.c:4648:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/mnt/glusterfs'.
[2013-02-19 21:18:48.036389] I [glusterfsd.c:1666:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.3.1
[2013-02-19 21:19:51.210472] E [socket.c:1715:socket_connect_finish] 0-glusterfs: connection to  failed (Connection timed out)
[2013-02-19 21:19:51.210751] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1787:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: failed to connect with remote-host: Transport endpoint is not connected
[2013-02-19 21:19:51.210782] I [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1790:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: -1 connect attempts left
[2013-02-19 21:19:51.211347] W [glusterfsd.c:831:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_transport_notify+0x28) [0x7fde6181e018] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0xc0) [0x7fde61822850] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs() [0x40c066]))) 0-: received signum (1), shutting down
[2013-02-19 21:19:51.211452] I [fuse-bridge.c:4648:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/mnt/glusterfs'.
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: My security group allows: port 22, 11, 24007-24009

Comment: Does `glusterserver1` resolve? Is the Gluster server running? Can you mount the brick from the server itself?

Comment: glusterserver is running. ping glusterserver is not responding

Comment: This command "sudo gluster volume info" results => 

Volume Name: vdgluster_vol_0
Type: Replicate
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: glusterserver1:/export/brick1
Brick2: glusterserver2:/export/brick1

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi @Danny Shepherd. The version of server and clients were different. I insalled same version, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. check the security group of server instances. Just to make sure it is not because of security group enable ALL Traffic for all the server instances.
2. instead of fstab try to mount using 
   mount.glusterfs server:vol mountpoint
3. check if the volume is started ?
   gluster volume vol-name status | start